# Webform not displaying

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have to port an application to .NET, so I decided to go with ASP Webforms.
I have my sample database (which is empty) set up and I have a few webforms (GridView, DetailsView). For a 'new' record page, I have a DetailView, but when I run it the server doesnt serve any form. I suspect it is because the tables are empty, so how do I set it up so it renders the form so I can add a New record.
Thanks, Also if anyone could point me to a good Webforms tutorial that covers the basics it would be great. Google has millions of those but most of them, including the msdn are cumbersome and get into lots of details that confuse me.

Comment: I think you will need to post some code. The relevant part of the aspx page and the Page_Load of the code behind would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do in this case is use the `<EmptyDataTemplate>` Field. This happens because when the DataSet is empty, the Form doesnt renders anything unless it's specified in the `EmptyDataTemplate`.